# Elastic Search,lowercase search doesnt work

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to search again content using prefix and if I search for diode I get results that differ from Diode. How do I get ES to return result where both diode and Diode return the same results? This is the mappings and settings I am using in ES.

```
"settings":{
   "analysis": {
   "analyzer": {
      "lowercasespaceanalyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
       "tokenizer": "whitespace",
       "filter": [
         "lowercase"
       ]
     }
   }
  }   
 },
"mappings": {
"articles": {
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "url": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "true"
    },
    "imageurl": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "true"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer" : "lowercasespaceanalyzer",
      "search_analyzer":"whitespace"
      },
    "description": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "relatedcontentwords": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "cmskeywords": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "partnumbers": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "true"
    },
    "pubdate": {
      "type": "date"
     }
    }
   }
 }

 here is an example of the query I use 
 POST _search
 {
   "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "prefix" : { "content" : "capacitance" }
        }
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: what version of elastic you are on

Comment: can you also show us the queries you have tried and errors you are getting?

Comment: An example that reproduces what you're seeing would really help

Comment: @user3775217 -- version 5.4.3

Comment: @RussCam -- So I just added a sample query and I get different results for Capacitance and capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no term of `Diode` in your index. So if you want to get same results, you should let your query context analyzed by same analyzer.

You can use [Query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) like

```
"query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "content",
        "query" : "Diode",
        "analyzer" :  "lowercasespaceanalyzer"
    }
```

**UPDATE**

You can analyze your context before query.

```
AnalyzeResponse resp = client.admin().indices()
                             .prepareAnalyze(index, text)
                             .setAnalyzer("lowercasespaceanalyzer")
                             .get();
String analyzedContext = resp.getTokens().get(0);
...
```

Then use `analyzedContext` as new query context.

Comment: I need to use prefix because the calls being made are for must and should query.

Comment: You can analyze your context before query. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you use two different analyzers at search time and at indexing time. 
So when you input query "Diod" at search time because you use "whitespace" analyzer your query is interpreted as "Diod".
However, because you use "lowercasespaceanalyzer" at index time "Diod" will be indexed as "diod". Just use the same analyzer both at search and index time, or analyzer that lowercases your strings because default "whitespace" analyzer doesn't https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html

Comment: I used this as the basis of my sample . [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454956/elasticsearch-analyzer-lowercase-and-whitespace-tokenizer). 

Idea being that I would like to tokenize words by space and analyze the words so that Capacitance and capacitance return the same results

Comment: Just try to use as "search_analyzer" and "analyzer" lowercasespaceanalyzer and you will see it will work. If you want to know why read ES documentation about inverted index and full-text search.